# checking properties of arguments passed to function we spyOn

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I'm trying to figure out (not successfully yet) if it's possible to check if js function I'm trying to mock with spyOn (jasmine) was called with the exact parameters I expected, for example consider function:

```
foo = function(date, array) {};
```

So far I can only make sure that the array was indeed passed like this:

```
spyOn(bar, 'foo').and.returnValue(somePromise.promise);
somePromise.resolve;
//call some function that calls 'foo' eventually...
expect(bar.foo).toHaveBeenCalledWith('10/12/2100', []);
```

I need to check if the array passed to this function was empty, how can I achieve this? Also if it's possible, how can I check if array passed to this function contained the string I wanted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace `and.returnValue` with `and.callFake`, then pass in a function that stores the arguments before returning the promise. Then the arguments can be used for later expect tests.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Jasmine, so this will probably not be the answer you're looking for.
On the other hand, it is a doable work around that you can implement in the mean time while you await your real answer.

If you have control over `foo`, then in the `foo` method you can tell it to set a global variable to its input parameter:

```
var fooParam;

var foo = function(array){
   fooParam = array;
}
```

Then in your other code, you can do:

```
if (fooParam != null){
   if (fooParam.contains(yourString)){
       //I'm not sure if "contains" is actually a method or not, 
       //but that's really a separate issue.
   }
}
```

So you set the global variable `fooParam` in the `foo` method and then you can use it later to do checking.

So there's a potential problem in that you might not have control over `foo`, such as if it's a system method. To work around that, replace all calls to `foo` with something like `foo2`, which you would define to have the same parameters and all it does is call `foo` and set the global variable. But if you have control of `foo`, then you don't need to do this.

The other potential problem is that `foo` will be called multiple times (such as if it's called within a loop). To circumvent this, you might make the global variable be an array list and have `foo` add its parameters to the array list instead of setting the variable. But if it's not called within a loop, or not called multiple times before it can be processed, then you don't need to do this.

I hope this helps while you're looking for the real answer

Comment: Hi, that's a little bit like how spies work. Rather than editing foo, what they do is replace foo with a function which logs the call, then optionally goes on to call the original foo method. That way the logged values can be kept inside the spy rather than having to be global.

Comment: Doable. but I needed proper solyution, hence I had to accept the other answer. Thank you anyway and enjoy your +10 points :)

Comment: No problem. Glad to you got the answer you were looking for